# KendoUI Editable Grid with german DatePicker

Tags: asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, datepicker, grid

**Edit**

The main question has been answered (use `kendo.ToString(value, format)` inside the `ClientTemplate(string)`). The following question is still open:
If a cell has no content (=empty string) and some value in its row has been edited, it shows for a moment a `null` during the update-event. How can this be suspended?

**Edit end**

Using the KendoUI Grid (from Telerik) with the ASP.NET MVC wrapper I have some (for me) unexplainable behaviours regarding editable cells.

Since our Grid needs to be filled with different types of data, the binding model uses the type `string` for all columns and chooses the editor template via explicit definition. There is no metadata bound to the fields about being editable or not in the model, since potentially every column could be editable. Non-editable cells just call `this.closeCell()` in the handler for the edit-event.

Using the Kendo DatePicker:

The DatePicker is configured to use a german styled date format `.Format("dd.MM.yyyy").Culture("de-DE")`. The DatePicker is in german and the date displayed, while still being inside the cell, uses the defined format.
This is good: [image: 10.03.2015]

As soon as I click outside of the cell, the format switches to an english long format: [image: Tue Mar 10 2015 0:00:00 GMT+0100]

The value sent to my backend via the update function of the datasource has a third format: [image: 10.03.2015 00:00:00]

Can anyone explain to me, how I can consistently in all three cases use the german date like in the first case (i.e. "10.03.2015")?

Another thing:
If a cell has no content (=empty string) and some value in its row has been edited, it shows for a moment a `null` during the update-event. How can this be suspended?

Additional Information:

- Javascript calls in the beginning the function `kendo.culture("de-DE");`
- `kendo.culture.de-DE.min.js` is included.
- The web.config uses `<globalization uiCulture="de-DE" culture="de-DE"/>` in the `<system.web>` section.
- Kendo version used: 2014.3.1119

Code:

Relevant part of the Grid in the View:

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid<SubfileModel>()
    .Name("SubfileGrid")
    .Columns(columns =>
    {
        Dictionary<string, string> alignment = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        alignment.Add("", "left");
        alignment.Add(" ", "left");
        alignment.Add("L", "left");
        alignment.Add("Z", "center");
        alignment.Add("C", "center");
        alignment.Add("R", "right");

        for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
        {
            if (Model.GridMeta.columns.Count >= i && Model.GridMeta.columns[i].Header != "")
            {
                columns.Bound(p => p.Fields[i].Content)
                    .HtmlAttributes(new { style = "text-align:" + alignment[Model.GridMeta.columns[i].Alignment], @class = (Model.GridMeta.columns[i].Monospaced ? "monospace" : "") + (Model.GridMeta.columns[i].Uppercase ? " uppercase" : "") })
                    .HeaderHtmlAttributes(new { style = "text-align:" + alignment[Model.GridMeta.columns[i].Alignment], @class = (Model.GridMeta.columns[i].Monospaced ? "monospace" : "") + (Model.GridMeta.columns[i].Uppercase ? " uppercase" : "") })
                    .ClientTemplate("#= fillContentTemplate(Fields[" + i + "].Color, Fields[" + i + "].Image, Fields[" + i + "].Content, Fields[" + i + "].Error)#")
                    .EditorTemplateName("SubfileEditor" + Model.GridMeta.columns[i].Type)
                    .FooterTemplate("<div class='gridFooter' style='text-align:" + alignment[Model.GridMeta.columns[i].Alignment] + "'>" + Model.GridMeta.columns[i].Footer + "</div>")
                    .EditorViewData(new { length = Model.GridMeta.columns[i].Length, negative = Model.GridMeta.columns[i].Negative, matchcodes = Model.GridMeta.columns[i].Matchcode, number = i.ToString() })
                    .Title(Model.GridMeta.columns[i].Header)
                    .Width(Math.Max(Model.GridMeta.columns[i].Header.Length * 12 + 40, Convert.ToInt32(Model.GridMeta.columns[i].Length.Substring(0, Model.GridMeta.columns[i].Length.IndexOf(","))) * 12));
            }
        }
    })
    .Editable(e => e.Mode(GridEditMode.InCell).Enabled(Model.GridMeta.editable))
    .Selectable(e => e.Mode(GridSelectionMode.Single).Type(GridSelectionType.Cell)) )
```

Models used:

```
public class SubfileModel2 //Overall Model to the View
{
    public GridMeta GridMeta { get; set; }
    public DetailsFields[,] WindowContent { get; set; }
}

public class GridMeta //Metainformation of the Grid
{
    public List<ColumnMeta> columns { get; set; }
    public bool editable { get; set; }
    public bool footerUsed { get; set; }
}

public class ColumnMeta //Metainformation of the Columns
{
    public string Header { get; set; }
    public string Alignment { get; set; }
    public string Type { get; set; }
    public bool Monospaced { get; set; }
    public bool Uppercase { get; set; }
    public string Length { get; set; }
    public bool Negative { get; set; }
    public List<SelectListItem> Matchcode { get; set; }
    public string Footer { get; set; }
}

public class SubfileModel //Content (Rows) of the Grid
{
    public string Table { get; set; }           
    public string Program { get; set; }         
    public bool IsSelected { get; set; }

    public int RRN { get; set; }                
    public int errorRRN { get; set; }

    public string NonSelectable { get; set; }   

    public string BackgroundColor { get; set; } 

    public List<FieldInformation> Fields { get; set; }
}

public class FieldInformation //Cells of a Row
{
    public string Content { get; set; }   
    public string Type { get; set; }      
    public string Type2 { get; set; }     
    public string Length { get; set; }    
    public string Align { get; set; }     
    public string Image { get; set; }     
    public string IsNegative { get; set; }
    public string Color { get; set; }     
    public bool   Error { get; set; }     
    public bool   Editable { get; set; }  
    public string SQLQuery { get; set; }
}
```

EditorTemplate in question:

```
@model string
@(Html.Kendo().DatePicker()
    .Name("Fields_" + (string)ViewData["number"] + "__Content")
    .HtmlAttributes(new { name = "Fields[" + (string)ViewData["number"] + "].Content", data_bind = "value:Fields[" + (string)ViewData["number"] + "].Content" })
    .Format("dd.MM.yyyy")
    .Culture("de-DE")
)
```

Comment: How do you expect to get help if you don't post your code?

Comment: @Pluc Oops. Sorry for that. This happens, when you get disturbed while composing a post.

Comment: I'm assuming `Fields[i].Content` is your date. Usually you could just set the format with `.Format(string)` on your column builder, but since you used `.ClientTemplate(string)`, it will be ignored. You need to use `kendo.toString(value, format)` in your client template. For the data sent to the server, It shouldn't happen. Either there's code missing to find out where the problem is or it's a problem regarding the usage of array (which isn't supported by Kendo's Grid) or you are miss-interpreting your debug information. By default, kendo's grid send dates in Json format.

Comment: Using `kendo.toString(value, format)` inside of the `.ClientTemplate(string)` was the key. Now the date stays in the german format (the backend still gets sent the date+time value, but that can be parsed away) . Thank you very much @Pluc.